# How to install the package scikit-geometry?

Tags: python, installation, package, scikits

I am trying to compute a class of Minkowski sums for some mathematical work, but there are too many to do by hand in a reasonable amount of time. I found this [documentation](https://scikit-geometry.github.io/scikit-geometry/introduction.html) for a package called `scikit-geometry`, but when I write `import skgeom as sg` as in the examples in the documentation, VSCode can't find the module.

The documentation says nothing about installation methods, and since I assume I need to install the package, I tried using similar methods as other scikit packages; e.g. `python -m pip install -U scikit-geometry` in the command line; but none of them work. In the case of the command line, I get:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement scikit-geometry (from versions: none)
> ERROR: No matching distruction found for scikit-geometry

I'm a complete beginner to anything past basic implementation of algorithms (as I am a pure mathematician by training), so I'm not sure where to go from here. I would like to be able to use the package, but I do not know enough computer science to specifically describe the issue I am having-- I hope that this post is detailed enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use conda try this :
`conda install -c conda-forge scikit-geometry`

If this does not work, install CGAL 5.0 and try it again:
`python -m pip install -e . -v`

I found this introduction to Scikit Geometry right here : https://wolfv.medium.com/introducing-scikit-geometry-ae1dccaad5fd

Comment: On Ubuntu, to install CGAL you can just `apt-get install libcgal-dev`